# Convert epoch time in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

Is there a simple way to convert Epoch time to standard format with Ruby? If so can I customize the way it is displayed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `Time.at` method:

```
Time.at(1234567890) #=> 2009-02-13 16:31:30 -0700
```

To display the time, you can use the method [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) on the resulting object.

For instance:

```
Time.at(1234567890).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") #=> "02/13/2009"
```